# ending statements in algorithm2e environment

Tags: punctuation, algorithm2e

I am using the package `algorithm2e`. Is there a way to end with period instead of semicolon, or end with simply newline? I don't like the semicolons on the sentences. If I just try putting a period it will put both sentences together which I don't want to do.

```
Compute the modulated input across this connection\;
Add the modulated input to the accumulated input\;
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Would it be sufficient if the semicolons are not visible in the resulting DVI or PDF file? Then you could give the command `\DontPrintSemicolon` a try. If you want a period you could try `\SetEndCharOfAlgoLine{.}` instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
Compute the modulated input across this connection.\\
Add the modulated input to the accumulated input.\\
```

works for me.