# Algorithm2e - Unwanted semi-colon

Tags: algorithm2e

With the following code, I have an unwanted semi-colon at the end of the loop condition.

[image]

Here is MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[lined]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \Begin{
        \uIf{Condition}{
                \Repeat{Stop}{Action}
        }
    }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

How can I change this ?

Comment: Related Question: [ending statements in algorithm2e environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7380/ending-statements-in-algorithm2e-environment).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can also use `\DontPrintSemicolon`.

Answer (score 9):

Use `\SetEndCharOfAlgoLine{}`:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[lined]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\SetEndCharOfAlgoLine{}

\begin{algorithm}
    \Begin{
        \uIf{Condition}{
                \Repeat{Stop}{Action}
        }
    }
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. It is strange that there is semi-colons for REPEAT loop but not for WHILE loop.

Comment: The OP also has this mistake but there really should have been an `end` closing the `if`, just as there is an `end` closing the `begin`. It would be nice if you could fix this to show how to use the package properly.